# This table is a No Primary Index(NOPI) table." on Teradata tables with a PI

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am currently testing out a pipeline where I am using "Hash" partition option to extract from an on-prem Database. I have set up a pipeline that passes a list of tables to a ForEach activity and then I run the extract in parallel:

[image]

Inside the ForEach activity I have put the following for the source tab:

[image]

When I run the pipeline I am getting the following errors on a lot of the Teradata tables:

{
"errorCode": "2200",
"message": "ErrorCode=TeradataNoPrimaryIndexTable,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=This table is a No Primary Index(NOPI) table. Please specify the partition column name in copy activity.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,'",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Copy data1",
"details": []
}

What confuses me is that when I check the Teradata tables I can see that there is a Primary Index. For example this is what I see for one of the tables that "failed" when I tried to copy it:

[image]

Am I not setting up something correct? Do I also need to create a parameter that would capture the primary index columns? Or are the errors coming from the fact that there is no primary column and the table has only an index?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So just to give an update on this, the reason why I was having an issue is that Microsoft only applied the auto Partition option to Teradata tables that had a name of 30 characters or less.

The tables that I was using had table names that were greater than 30 characters and thus were failing because of a bug in ADF that could not recognize how to auto-partition it. I have raised this issue with Microsoft and they are planning on putting out a patch (will update once that is done).

The way I solved the above question is that I had to separate out the pipeline where if the name is less or equal to 30 characters it was sent to a ForEach activity with a Copy activity nested inside it that used the Auto-Parition option.

The rest of the tables (which were greater than 30 characters) were sent to a different ForEach activity where I had chosen a "load_date" column that we put on all of our incoming tables in Teradata. It was not the best solution, but it at least helped speed up our copying.

Below is a picture of how my pipeline looks:

[image]

Hope this helps someone else that might have been having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think as per the blog PK is required .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-teradata#parallel-copy-from-teradata

**Partition option: Hash.**

During execution, Data Factory automatically detects the PK column, applies a hash against it, and copies data by partitions.

Comment: Hi @HimanshuSinha-msft, I actually opened a git hub ticket with Microsoft because that does not seem accurate. I did initial tests and it looks like instead of looking for a PK column ADF seems to search for "Partition By" column. I tried this with a couple of tables and only the tables that had Partition By worked.

I asked Microsoft for verification and have 2 open tickets in the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-teradata